# After resuming, everything works except screen is blank

Tags: suspend, intel

I'm trying to get ubuntu to run on my acer tablet/laptop (Acer Aspire SW3-016/Gummi CHT, BIOS V1.15 04/21/2016). Most things work, except when it suspends I can't resume. Or rather, it does resume because I can hear sounds, type commands, switch to VTs etc. - only I can't see anything because the screen is black. I can adjust screen brightness up and down and see the difference, but it is still just a black screen. I suspect this is a problem with intel graphics drivers (Cherrytrail), but after significant searching I still have no idea where to start, as this seems to be a different problem from most suspend/resume issues.

Any ideas?

Comment: What Intel graphics does your laptop have? What Acer model do you have? Which Ubuntu version are you installing. Are you selecting Wayland or Xorg? Gnome or Unity?

Comment: I'm trying the latest (19.10) ubuntu, as well as derivatives like Pop and alternatives like fedora. All have the same result. It doesn't matter if I'm using Wayland or Xorg, gdm, llightdm or any dm. Same result on all.

Comment: Did you try to use the `tty` console mode? Probably just the GUI has an issue, switch to `tty` using **Ctrl** + **Alt** + **F1** shortcut (go back to GUI using **Ctrl** + **Alt** + **F7** shortcut)

Comment: Hi, no, like I said in the description, I can switch to the VTs after resume and even type commands - I just can't see any of that on the screen.

Comment: Progress! I plugged in an external display. When I resume, although the laptop screen is black, the external display comes on and shows the usual secondary monitor background. However, no matter what I do with display settings, the laptop screen never comes back on until I reboot. Does this give any hints about how to proceed?